# jq extract data including ObjectId

Tags: jq, bson

This data i'm trying to extract fields like "n","fn" however its weird i can't using jq

```
jq -r '[.n, .fn] 

{ "_id" : ObjectId( "575a7c43df2e246028c9c0d2" ), "_class" : "com.go.next.cms.entity.User", "n" : "Rahul Joshi", "fn" : "Rahul", "ln" : "Joshi", "un" : "1198383883", "p" : "av3o1fo6h236j5bu9ue8oq380jm1t7p", "e" : "a@gmail.com", "emailVerified" : true, "k" : "55394505-dd92-4b1a-b96a-a1c433662abc", "o_tokens" : { "575a7c43df2e246028c9c0d2~iximacb~411e35964795733b" : "6dghooxc0bxhsj9vmw2e4bu5aav3o1fo6h236j5bu9ue8oq3w13r2jd73ku8hbjhkjesa80jm1t7pmsaarmaupndhcb1disieobpkarokhc29880suct42kppmrfqjy948ufmhifdew9depicf9y5wqchlba66nl5roww35ee0b4jqwkm04b9rb8one1u4h7dlp", "575a7c43df2e246028c9c0d2~iximaad~411e35964795733b" : "liwscmgb9an3111y2oxu0xabu3qcrmxwjpjntof3r6ax7pmp0hx65xpyp5jm0bkogq0ddkg18gnlr5nofssge6lodlk3focpwee1tlilye4n9h01m5u9odxpkma2kovl4ilgseoijl99y680j6i57643jm8t0dqcwxm0pde7w1rngusb0voljn2xwp8vbwbdnqx", "575a7c43df2e246028c9c0d2~iximatr~8577b27bf06cd78" : "j8vs2ymueh03hifiowfhij79sd2gcng2gd3sgb6frxs09xi443xumwe9rfvs2ps3o1ol63pib7aqhqit3eg0evjq6dawu9a3uj70cd0kf2i41bnp3n0q7ry3vblso0bb51y3ktvyq390h8192uusupe1pwui7h76fyq9a8ryo8jbspaomsl147ifp1npcpsrte2", "575a7c43df2e246028c9c0d2~iximaad~8577b27bf06cd78" : "m8gnne9cwadtwq0s0r43p7788h43hn3f9m3g1h6hagvdm8v9x6d7mvfuyuq97rhx6axobs8p2fac5wrie3a6pyaia5aq320eeh60lggbtuu816rhfg42rg3b46x356dujeo1fyeu1cawlupst78hudmx283dtg76wdalsfhij34pjx1i8tdydpihipsjysctwio" }, "wc" : 0, "role" : [ "registered_user" ], "metaUserId" : 1980469, "t" : "ya29.GlslBaPrIStUyWrejOrmxAui7DkbLRg8wzAE1Aj73U-X7rhxFLekZWPu-z_ywUS-OWO2VVcbTIPC37XorBHg-2vvkJmpqov1uPCmR5HKHW_gbcEKU6FZApW4wJYq", "rt" : "1/isjRuytVLOeMVAytcvNVTWp_radi88Nc40IqzXOJQGvhufKyPjE99hZyGUzbWFmd", "up" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/DpBXPPCkSk0/photo.jpg", "ad" : { "_id" : null, "countryCode" : "in", "_v" : 0, "_cd" : Date( 1465547843305 ), "_ugc" : false, "_inflow" : false }, "au" : false, "po" : 0, "friends" : 0, "rejectedReviews" : 0, "ex" : false, "usrc" : "iximaad", "ld" : Date( 1480425174813 ), "age" : 0, "contactNumber" : { "number" : "931128098", "prefix" : "91", "emailId" : "a@gmail.com" }, "contactNumberVerified" : true, "travellers" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId( "5a366b73ba9e7f124f496060" ), "travellerType" : "Adult", "title" : "Mr", "firstName" : "Rahul ", "lastName" : "Joshi", "editableTraveller" : true, "primary" : false, "frequentFlierNumberList" : [], "seniorCitizen" : false, "_v" : 0, "_cd" : Date( 1513515891223 ), "_ugc" : false, "_inflow" : false }, { "_id" : ObjectId( "5a366ba14f173f177ebda9ec" ), "travellerType" : "Adult", "title" : "Mr", "firstName" : "Pritash", "lastName" : "Thakar ", "editableTraveller" : true, "primary" : false, "frequentFlierNumberList" : [], "seniorCitizen" : false, "_v" : 0, "_cd" : Date( 1513515937071 ), "_ugc" : false, "_inflow" : false } ], "totalRewardPoints" : 0, "reedemedRewardPoints" : 0, "activityRewardPoints" : {}, "activityTotalRewardPoints" : {}, "ltc" : false, "loginType" : "signup", "otpVerified" : true, "verifiedNumber" : "9320119998", "gcmId" : [], "prc" : 0, "accounts" : {}, "en" : true, "migrated" : false, "mailAccounts" : {}, "partnerUserParams" : { "go" : { "partnerUserId" : "118108096894957046911" } }, "places" : {}, "_v" : 0, "_cd" : Date( 1465547843305 ), "_ugc" : false, "_inflow" : false }
```

How i can slove this problem ?

Comment: The provided JSON is not valid. Fix it from https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "JSON" is actually BSON, which can be converted to JSON using bsondump provided by MongoDB (see e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/bsondump/).  There are other BSON-to-JSON tools you can find by googling.

**If** your BSON is sufficiently small (as is the case with your sample), another possibility would be to handle it as though it is jq source code; you would of course also have to provide functions such as `ObjectId`, e.g. like so:

```
def ObjectId($s): "ObjectID:\($s)";
def Date($s): "Date:\($s)";
```

Using this approach with your BSON and query, invoking jq with the -n option yields:

```
[
  "Rahul Joshi",
  "Rahul"
]
```